# Regarding "make install"

Tags: makefile, cmake, installation

I was installing [OpenGV](http://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/page_installation.html) and it is said there that

> At least under Linux and OSX, the installation on the host OS (including the headers) can be activated by simply setting INSTALL_OPENGV to ON.

Is this meant for the `make install`? At least that is how I understand it.

If that is the case, why in the dockerfile of the [OpenSfM](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM/blob/master/Dockerfile) (this library depends on the OpenGV), it is like this?

```
# Install opengv from source
RUN \
    mkdir -p /source && cd /source && \
    git clone https://github.com/paulinus/opengv.git && \
    cd /source/opengv && \
    mkdir -p build && cd build && \
    cmake .. -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON && \
    make install && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf /source/opengv
```

The flag for `INSTALL_OPENGV` is not set to on and yet, it is ok to `make install`. Looking at the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/laurentkneip/opengv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) file of the OpenGV, the `INSTALL_OPENGV` flag is default to OFF.

Comment: Maybe OpenSfM does only need the headers?  I don't think your question is on-topic here.  Or I misunderstand your question. You understood the purpose of INSTALL_OPENGV the right way. Why OpenSfM uses it that way, would be a good question asked them.

Comment: Actually I am trying to know the flow of make install. Since I am new into this cmake things, I am trying to get the grasp of how it works.

Comment: This is specific to OpenGV. If you want to learn the use of CMake by OpenGV, this is the wrong place to ask. If you want to learn the CMake install process, you should have a look into more libraries and read some documentation and tutorial. This question is not well suited here.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from `CMakeLists.txt`, when `INSTALL_OPENGV` is `OFF`, only headers are installed.

When the flag is `ON`, it also installs binaries produced by the `opengv` target.

CMake's `install` target is a default target that gets generated even if there are no `install()` calls in `CMakeLists.txt`. In that case `make install` would simply do nothing.